# count the checkboxes selected using C#

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I have a SharePoint custom list which has a column Status (`CheckBox`). I want to count the total number of list items that are checked and need to show it in a label.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the checkbox control value as

```
SPFieldMultiChoiceValue choices = new SPFieldMultiChoiceValue(item["MultiChoice"].ToString());
```

And iterate through the values as

```
for (int i = 0; i < choices.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(choices[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanq for ur reply Saksham

Answer (score -2):

Cycle through the controls and check if it is a checkbox.  If it is then check if it is checked.  If it is then add to the count.  Display the count at the end.

```
        int count = 0;
        foreach (var control in this.Controls)
        {
            if (control is CheckBox)
            {
                if (((CheckBox)control).Checked)
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Count: " + count);
```

You can replace the MessageBox with a label.

Comment: May i know how to like it